# Simple Line, escaped elements with different type

Tags: boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

i want to parse the following line with boost::spirit

```
0  "a"  "b"  "c"
```

I've created my rules like this:

```
qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, std::string()> escaped_ = qi::char_('"') >> *(qi::char_ - qi::char_('"')) >> qi::char_('"');

int id;
std::string v1,v2,v3;

qi::phrase_parse(bein, end, (qi::int_ >> escaped_ >> escaped_ >> escaped_ >> qi::eol), id, v1, v2, v3);
```

But the parsing failed and i don't know why. Hopefully someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`phrase_parse` takes (it, it, parser, skipper[, attribute...]). You forgot to pass a skipper:

```
bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(begin, end, (qi::int_ >> escaped_ >> escaped_ >> escaped_ >> qi::eol), qi::blank, id, v1, v2, v3);
```

I suggest `qi::blank` there because your grammar treats `eol` as significant (skipping it would never match).

> **Note** the `qi::rule` subtly omits the skipper, hence it's implicitly a `lexeme[]`:
>
> ```
> qi::rule<It, std::string(), qi::blank_type> escaped_ = qi::lexeme['"' >> *(qi::char_ - '"') >> '"'];
> ```
>
> See also: [Boost spirit skipper issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965)

Final note, you like didn't want to parse `"` as part of the resulting values (change `qi::char_('"')` into `qi::lit('"')` or, equivalently `'"'` if possible).

## Demo

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f68296a36e8f616b)**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main() {
    typedef std::string::const_iterator It;

    qi::rule<It, std::string()> escaped_ = '"' >> *(qi::char_ - '"') >> '"';

    std::string const input("0  \"a\"  \"b\"  \"c\"\n");
    It begin(input.begin()), end(input.end());

    int id;
    std::string v1,v2,v3;

    bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(begin, end, (qi::int_ >> escaped_ >> escaped_ >> escaped_ >> qi::eol), qi::blank, id, v1, v2, v3);

    if (ok) {
        std::cout << "Parse succeeded:" 
                  << " "  << id
                  << " '" << v1 << "'"
                  << " '" << v2 << "'"
                  << " '" << v3 << "'\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
    }

    if (begin != end)
        std::cout << "Remaining unparsed '" << std::string(begin, end) << "'\n";

}
```

Prints

```
Parse succeeded: 0 'a' 'b' 'c'
```

Comment: bad to contact you again, is there a possibility for Skype ? or not public chat ?